# Rspec Controller Post Create with Twilio Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, twilio

I am new to Rspec testing so sorry if the problem in my code is obviously wrong. I am trying to test if when sending a sms message to my Twilio number that it saves.

Here is my controllers/messages_controller.rb

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class MessagesController < AppController
  include Webhookable

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    Message.create!(parent_id: nil,
               content_type: "sms",
               content: params['Body'],
               origin: params['From'].gsub("+1", ""),
               destination: params['To'].gsub("+1", ""),
               received_at: Time.now())
respond_to do |format|
  format.all { render :nothing => true, :status => 200 }
end
end

end
```

Here is my spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb where I used let!() to create a bunch of objects that the create method uses in its callbacks

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MessagesController, :type => :controller do
describe "#create" do
    let(:message) { build(:message) }
    let!(:hotel)  { create(:hotel) }
    let!(:group)  { create(:group) }
    let!(:guest)  { create(:test_guest) }
    let!(:user)   { create(:user) }
    let!(:visit)  { create(:visit) }
    let!(:group_user) { create(:group_user) }

    context "when new text message comes in" do
        it "saves the message" do
            post :create, :Body => message.content, :From => message.origin, :To => message.destination
            expect(Message.last).to be_truthy
        end
    end
end
end
```

Here is the failed message when I run the test

```
Failures:

1) MessagesController#create when new text message comes in saves the message
 Failure/Error: let!(:visit)  { create(:visit) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/hotel.rb:30:in `managers'
 # ./app/models/concerns/visit_message.rb:9:in `create_check_in_messages'
 # ./spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

From there I went a checked models/hotel.rb:30

```
def managers
groups.first.users.managers.order("created_at ASC")
end
```

However, I thought since I used let!(:group) { create(:group) } that this would not be nil when I run the test. Any direction or constructive criticism would much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can see is that the order in which you create your objects is not right

```
let(:message) { build(:message) }
let!(:hotel)  { create(:hotel) }
let!(:group)  { create(:group) }
let!(:user)   { create(:user) }
let!(:group_user) { create(:group_user, :group => group, :user => user) }
let!(:guest)  { create(:test_guest) }
let!(:visit)  { create(:visit) }
```

You should be creating group, `user` and the `join` record `group_user` with the proper group and user before creating the visit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and I understand your explanation. I made the adjustment, however, I'm still getting the same failure from above. Could it be that I'm not saving the objects correctly so when it goes into the 'groups' table there's nothing there? or is this a case where I need to stub out the 'manager' method?